# Delphi | Перерисовка высоты строк DBGridEh

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Имеется цикл, в котором перебираются гриды и записывается определенный размер шрифта. При этом размер высоты строк подстраивается только в том случае, когда я растягиваю грид. Пробовал обновить грид методом Refresh, но высота строк не изменяется. Как всё-таки сделать перерисовку высоты строк?

Answer (score 0):

Для начале проверьте есть ли у грида в options включённым параметр Titles. Если выключен, то включите. Объявите класс

```
 TMyCustomGridHack = Class(TCustomGrid)
   Public
     Property RowHeights;
 end;
```

Далее, в том месте где у вас строки кода меняют размер шрифта припишите

```
  TMyCustomGridHack(DBGrid1).RowHeights[0] := 20; //где 20, это значение, на которое следует увеличивать.
  DBgrid1.Update;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет, уже решил проблему). Использовал метод UpdateAllDataRowHeights, но почему-то перерисовка высоты строк идет дольше и программа зависает. Можно ли как-то распараллелить процесс?